# Netflix/Imdb Movie Genre Data Set

Tags: data-request, machine-learning, uses-of-open-data

Is anyone familiar with a dataset I can use to model or segment users of a data set into movie genres for users based on time, day, the device used, geographic demographics in a data set? I have a data set I want to connect with external data that would give me a preferred movie genre for that user based on the factors mentioned, I tried to find something from IMDb or Netflix, thanks for looking.

Comment: What do you mean “users”? Movie viewers?

Comment: Users as in just users of a a specific data set that visit websites @philshem

Comment: ok, so web logs, but what website?